# print from VirtualBox to networked printer

Tags: virtualbox, windows-xp, printing

I run Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit desktop edition and I have Panasonic networked printer KX - MX2000 printer.

There are no 64 bit drivers available from Panasonic for Ubuntu/debian. They only have 32 bit drivers for RHEL :( So - there is no way I can print from my computer to that networked printer directly.

So - my idea was to install printer drivers onto Windows XP VirtualBox guest and just printer from virtual machine.

I've installed XP drivers onto guest, VirtualBox network adapter set to Bridged, I can see printer in the browser from guest, I can ping printer from guest but when I try to print nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong. IS there something else I have to configure?

**UPDATE:**

Panasonic Red Hat drivers:
http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html

**TO INSTALL THEM ON UBUNTU**

```
sudo alien --scripts -k libjbig-1.0.0-1.i386.rpm libtetra-1.0.0-2.i386.rpm rastertogdi-1.0.1-9.i386.rpm

sudo dpkg -i libjbig_1.0.0-1_i386.deb libtetra_1.0.0-2_i386.deb rastertogdi_1.0.1-9_i386.deb

sudo service cups restart
```

now - there will be some errors during execution which shouldn't affect anything.

**BUT THE PROBLEM IS**

I cannot get it to work on Ubuntu Maverick 10.10 64 bits (or any other 64 bits distro for that reason. Only tried on Ubuntu 10.10 64 though.).  Any sugguestions guys? :) Thanks

Comment: hmmmm.... nevr mind.....

Comment: got it figured out...I was doing everything right. Just had to reinstall drivers in the guest Xp machine... go figure.....So glad I don't use windows anymore :)

Comment: Please consider deleting your question or rephrasing it so we can answer with something useful for others. Can you link to where you got the linux 32bit drivers?

Comment: sometimes alien can move something from rpm to deb...just a thought as something useful getting into the question

Comment: addedd manufacturer drivers link and conversion instructions for dwbian/ubuntu. IS there any way to install them on 64 bit Ubuntu Maverick though? Anyone? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get the 32bit driver installed on 64bit currently. But if you know you have a 32bit requirement it might be worth getting 32bit desktop instead.

As for virtual box, there is no reason I can think of why it wouldn't work. Try reinstalling the windows drivers and making sure the network is good.

Comment: Thanks. I've got it to work through Virtualbox which will do for now. Since I have 8 gb of Ram it seems like such a waste to use 32 bit version :) so I hope Panasonic will come out with 64 bit driver some time in the future.

Comment: You can still use 8gb of RAM on 32bit, just use the intel memory page extensions.